# Attach to running IE. pShellWindows.CreateInstance(__uuidof(SHDocVw::ShellWindows)); Error Class not registered

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer

I am trying to attach to running IE using the
pShellWindows.CreateInstance(__uuidof(SHDocVw::ShellWindows)); 
This fails with Error Class not registered.
The OS is Windows Server 2003 SP2. On other computers with the same 
OS the code works fine.

Comment: This method is described here http://support.microsoft.com/?id=176792

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
I never logged on with the user I was running into this computer interactively so IE had no chance to 
set up shell integration. After I logged on once the problem went away