# SHDocVw::IShellWindowsPtr fails with IE8? (Error 0x80040154)

Tags: c++, com, internet-explorer-8, mshtml

My program is a dll that hooks into a running instance of IE. It's worked fine for years.

Recently I dusted it off and ran it, but the last line below fails with `hr = 0x80040154`:

```
#import <mshtml.tlb>     rename("value", "theValue") rename("event", "theEvent")
#import <shdocvw.dll> 

// ....

SHDocVw::IShellWindowsPtr spSHWinds;
HRESULT hr = m_spSHWinds.CreateInstance(__uuidof(SHDocVw::ShellWindows));
```

Could it matter that IE7 has been replaced by IE8? Where else should I look?

I'm using VS2008, if that matters.

**Edited to add**

I don't see that it could be a 32/64 bit issue - it ran fine last year on this same machine. The only thing that's changed (as far as I have noticed) is the version of IE, from 7 to 8.

**Note to the bounty hunters:**

I only have access to this system for a few hours a day (around 0:00 EST), so you may not get quick responses to your suggestions, but I *will* look into them.

If you think there are things I should be checking (registry values, for example), be specific.

**Edited to add:**

I now see that the *first* time I call CreateInstance, it returns 0x80070002, not 0x80040154.

Comment: 0x80040154 is 'class not registered'. Maybe a 32/64-bit issue?

Comment: You have `0x80040154` `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` "Class not registered" error. The most probable is that you don't have this component installed. At least, this is the first thing to check: look into registry if you have any entries for this `CLSID` and if they point to a healthy DLL.

Comment: And then the next thing - if the DLL looks good for you - is to create an empty project, e.g. console C++ app, which simply does `CoInitialize` and `CoCreateInstance`, i.e. outside of IE, and have it a run to see if this one can instantiate the class.

Comment: @RomanR. : as you can see from the code, the DLL in this case is `shdocvw.dll`. How could this have gone bad without Vista breaking entirely? And as I mentioned, this code ran fine last year, on this same machine. The only change (as far as I recall) is IE8.

Comment: It does not have to break it entirely (esp. but not necessarily if your OS is x64 and most of the shell you see there is x64, as opposed to this supposedly Win32 code). The problem is that the broken system is yours and it should be easy to try, for others it is hard to try - they don't have your hooking project in first place.

Comment: Assign `__uuidof(SHDocVw::ShellWindows)` to a variable so you can dump it and make sure it contains what you think it contains.

Comment: @egrunin, the following question might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5071225/800524. Note also that [KB176792](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176792) says: "The previous method for connecting to a running instance of the Internet Explorer does not work if Shell Integration is not installed or if "Browse in a new process" is selected in Internet Explorer 4.0."

Answer (score 4):

That's going to be **very** hard to diagnose.  The ShellWindows coclass is special, its CLSID registry key is `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}`.  When you look there, you'll see nothing useful registered there.  The background story is that this is a leftover of an ill-fated attempt to make the Windows shell resemble a web browser.  Still visible today, enumerating the shell windows returns both Windows Explorer and Internet Explorer instances.

The SysInternals' ProcMon utility is almost always the weapon of choice to debug 0x80040154 errors but it falls flat here.  You can see it probing the registry, and not finding what it is looking for, but then the program knows how to load ieframe.dll anyway.  This can only work by the operating system intercepting the CoCreateInstance() call.  Which makes sense in general, considering the coclass enumerates shell windows.

All you got left is the trial-and-error approach.  Reinstall IE first, OS next.  Or to shove the machine out of a 4th story window before it eats too much of your valuable time.

Comment: +1 This is actually very useful because it will save me going down some dead ends.

Comment: +1 For some terrific advice and the 4th story window. You always have such great posts.